# What happened to everyone's downvotes?

Tags: support, down-votes, data-explorer

I composed this query on SEDE the other day: [Meanest users](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/2082/meanest-users) (users by ratio of downvotes)

If you look at the data displayed there and compare it to the current information on their profiles, you'll find that many of their downvotes simply vanished. Enter a mininum of 100 downvotes. [GEOCHET](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5640/geochet)'s profile shows s/he has 1840 downvotes, while the query says 3412, a difference of 1572.

The data on SEDE is only a couple of months old, so I think it's highly unlikely that this many posts have been deleted since then (and that's not taking into consideration that fact that these users have cast more downvotes in the meantime).

So what happened to everyone's downvotes?

Comment: It could be that these are downvotes on deleted posts ever, not only deleted posts since the last data dump (which is actually less then a month old, if I remember right). For me, it shows 534 down- and 1956 upvotes, while my profile shows 328+1916, i.e. also upvotes get lost (but presumably less so).

Comment: [Data dump creation date](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/2124/data-dump-creation-date): 2011-11-13 2:14:25

Comment: Wow, that Community user sure is a hard guy to please.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the vote count on users in the data dump represents *all* the votes they've ever cast. Even if the posts voted on were later deleted.

The counts on the profile pages reflect only votes that haven't been deleted.

Which is good news for the accuracy of your query!